# Creating an alert message in React.

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new in React,and managed to write down a tic tac toe program which works. What I want to add now,is an alert message to appear,if the users enters the correct combinations.

So here is my program.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
   super(props)

   this.state = {
       PLAYER_ONE_SYMBOL: "X",
       PLAYER_TWO_SYMBOL: "O",
       currentTurn: "X",
       board: [
        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""
       ]
   }
  }
  /*
   * @param index represents the position or index of each box
  */
  handleClick(index) {
    console.log(index);
    if(this.state.board[index] === "" && !this.state.winner) {
      this.state.board[index] = this.state.currentTurn
      this.setState({
        board: this.state.board,
        /* I am saying if the current turn is X change to 0 or change to X.   
 I use a turnary operator,as it is faster from if - else statements.  */  
        currentTurn: this.state.currentTurn === this.state.PLAYER_ONE_SYMBOL 
 ? this.state.PLAYER_TWO_SYMBOL : this.state.PLAYER_ONE_SYMBOL,
        winner: this.checkForWinner(),
      })
    }
 }
/*
A function that checks when the players wins. The logic is quite simple.    
First  I decrare the winning combination as an array.
Then I need to make sure the combination is not emtpy. And finally I am   
checking the combination.
*/   
checkForWinner() {
var currentTurn = this.state.currentTurn
var symbols = this.state.board
var winningCombos = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7],   
[2, 5, 8], [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]]
return winningCombos.find(function(combo) {
  if(symbols[combo[0]] !== "" && symbols[combo[1]] !== ""  &&   
symbols[combo[2]] !== ""  && symbols[combo[0]] === symbols[combo[1]] && 
symbols[combo[1]] === symbols[combo[2]]) {
    return currentTurn
  } else {
    return false
  }
})
}    
/* I am rendering whatever is on the board. */    
render() {
return (
  <div className="board">
      {this.state.board.map((cell,index) => {
        return <div onClick={() => this.handleClick(index)} 
className="square">{cell}</div>;   
      })}
  </div>
)
} 
}
export default App;
```

Any ideas on that?

Thanks,

Theo.

Comment: As Tricode said, you can just do `alert()` which works cross-platform. You won't be able to customize it's layout or styling though. That is determined by the browser. If you want more flexibility you would need to create your own. Something like bootstrap modal.

Comment: ok. thanks. I did it.